# Loading a single value into an array using C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have a simplified version of the problem I'm working on. In essence, I need to read a line of input and check which characters were used in it.

So if I had the line: "Joey likes Bread"

The output would be:"abdeijklors"

Input >> "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

Output >> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" (The Alphabet)

I SHOULD just be able to load it into an array- but that's not working.

Here is a sample of my code, simplified for only the alphabet. The lowering and raising of the ASCII value is solely for the sake of a good example of the 26 letters of the alphabet.

```
#include "letters.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void letters_used(char *line) {
        int c;
        int table[26]={0};
        int buff;

        //Go through the line and set values to 1 in each alphabetic position

        while (line) {
                c = *line;
                if (isalpha(c)) {
                        if isupper(c) {
                                c = tolower(c);
                        }
                        table[c-97]=1; //Lowering ASCII value for alphabetized order
                }
                line++;
        }

        //Walk through the array and print any true values

        int i;
        for (i=0;i<26;i++){
                c = table[i];
                if (c) {
                        c += 97 //Raising ASCII value back to normal
                        printf("%c", c);
                }
        }
        printf("\n");
```

But no matter what I do, the array isn't printing because the array's values are still set to 0. If I set them manually it works fine, but the second I throw it into the loop, I can't load values into the array and it stays at 0. Am I missing something stupidly obvious here?

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  You're close, but not there.

Comment: Your code is complete and doesn't compile.

Comment: Use integer constants like 'a' instead of 97.

Comment: PSA: Don't use *magical* numbers like `97` if you really mean `'a'`.

Comment: In the printing loop, you check whether `c` is zero, but you try to convert that count into a letter, instead of converting the index, `i`, into the letter.

Comment: `while(line)` is no good, you probably mean `*line`

Comment: After you fix `line` -> `*line` you'll need `printf("%c", c);` -> `printf("%c", i + 97);` unless you really like `b`.

Comment: You got a couple of good answers below.  Please accept the best one by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 4):

1. Eliminate the header you didn't tell us about.
2. Fix syntax errors.
3. Prefer `const` arguments to document that it doesn't change.
4. `while(line)` is incorrect; you want use `while(*line)` to test for the terminating`'\0'`.  Your program segfaults prior to this change.
5. Print loop is using the wrong variable `c + 'a'` when it should have been `i + 'a'`.  Otherwise you just get a bunch of 'b's.
6. Prefer `for` to `while` loop for iteration.
7. Call `tolower()` unconditionally instead of conditionally upon `isupper()`.  Makes the code a little simpler and you eliminate a branch.  I eliminated the variable `c` but it's ok to keep it, too.
8. (Not fixed) Prefer separating the algorithm from I/O.  The cleanest interface would be to return a dynamically allocated string (this also allows you to return NULL if `line == NULL`); alternative have caller pass in a suitable out parameter.  Caller then prints the string or whatever is needed.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void letters_used(const char *line) {
    int table['z' - 'a' + 1] = {0}; // Felt cute, might delete later
    for (; *line; line++)
        if (isalpha((unsigned char) *line))
            table[tolower((unsigned char) *line) - 'a'] = 1;
    for (size_t i=0; i < sizeof table / sizeof *table; i++)
        if (table[i])
            printf("%c", (char) i + 'a');
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    letters_used("Joey likes Bread");
}
```

and example output:

```
abdeijklorsy
```

Comment: You are correct- It looks like I forgot the pointer on "*line". Thanks for the save- I tried rubber ducking this for an hour, but was pulling my hair out. For some reason my compiler ran just fine and didn't throw any errors on the *line. Thanks a ton! As for the syntax, I just wrote this in the editor off of memory haha, I wasn't very rigorous.

Comment: The magic number `26` then calculating the size of the table feels like it would look better with `#define TABLE_SIZE 26` then `int table[TABLE_SIZE] = {0};` and `for (size_t i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)`

Comment: Never apologize.  It slows down your learning.  If that answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: @Chris While I generally agree with you, I think it's ok to have it one place, but there is an implicit dependency between that 26 and `c-'a'`.  Maybe `z` - `a` + 1?

Comment: For the `<ctype.h>` functions, you want to cast to `unsigned char` (or `unsigned int`). Casting to `int` doesn't make the problem of sign extension go away...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I don't entirely understand why you need to do the explicit cast opposed to just passing the char value in... I guess it's because it's a table implementation so I will do the `(unsigned char)` as hinted in man page.  Thanks.

Comment: When one goes beyond 7-bit ASCII into the extended 8-bit characters, that single byte with a set `b7` will be implicitly converted to an integer parameter... that is **negative**... The helpless `<ctype.h>` functions will faultlessly access their LUTs using a negative index. Cheers! :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 It's fair because it's documented but why doesn't the functions use an unsigned type or cast internally?

Comment: If plain `char` is a signed type and contains accented characters in the range `0x80`..`0xFF`, those are stored as negative values, and casting the negative value to `int` retains the negative value, but casting to `unsigned char` deals with the problem.  The argument to the `<ctype.h>` functions must be either EOF or a character converted to `unsigned char` — see [§7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>` ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4): _In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I get why I was wrong (initially) but I was wondering why ctype does it that way... EOF.  ok, got it.

Comment: Probably speed. The function would have to first AND with a mask (`0xFF`) to get back to a `signed int` (or `size_t`) index. If done by the caller, the compiler will emit the correct _unsigned_ operations, so the functions (called billions of times?) can get on with what they're supposed to do...

Comment: Yup, EOF.  And the specification matches the `int` values returned by [§7.21.7.1 The `fgetc` function](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1) and its friends: _[if there is a character to read,] the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` …_. Of course, an array of `char` never contains `EOF`, but since plain `char` can be a signed type, you have to take the precaution.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler TIL.

Comment: @AllanWind TIL "TIL" ... This is getting _recursive!!_ `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 I almost did a TIL for you too, buddy, but can't tag more than one person and your handle is too short and I had to write stuff... like be chatty and stuff :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void letters_used(const char *line)
{
    int c;
    int table[26] = {0};

    while ((c = (unsigned char)*line++) != '\0')
    {
        if (isalpha(c))
            table[tolower(c) - 'a'] = 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (table[i] != 0)
            printf("%c", i + 'a');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    letters_used("Joey likes Bread");
    letters_used("The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog");
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the output:

```
abdeijklorsy
abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz
```

The key point is using `i` and not `c` in the call to `printf()` in the printing loop. (In the question, the printing loop contains `c = table[i];` and `printf("%c", c + 97);`.)  I also revised the `while` loop to scan the input correctly, avoiding splitting the loop control over multiple lines.  The code casts the letters to `unsigned char` before using it in the `isalpha()` and `tolower()` functions; this protects the code on systems where the plain `char` type is a signed type and the user types characters with codes in the range 0x80..0xFF.  Note that `tolower()` can be called unconditionally; it doesn't modify letters that are already in lower case, nor does it modify non-letters.  I used `'a'` instead of `97` because it is clearer what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
c = table[i];
```

always will be 1 or 0. So here:

```
c += 97 //Raising ASCII value back to normal
```

always be 'a' or 'b'.

Then, what would you want to get here? May be you mean `c = (char)(i + 97)`?

Comment: It would be better to use `'a'` instead of `97`.  The `c += 97` will only happen when `c != 0` which means it is always `1` and hence the mapped character is always `b`.